# Angular2 routing and Cancelling Observables mid stream

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have an Angular Http get request that will navigate the route to one of three routes depending on the data returned. Sample code below:

SomeComponent:

```
constructor(
   private someService: SomeService,
   private router: Router
) { }

ngOnInit() {
   this.someService.getSomeData().subscribe(
      () => {
         console.log("getSomeData() did not route to a new link! Routing to a 3rd link");
         this.router.navigate(['home']);
      },
      () => {
         console.log("Some error occurred.");
      });
```

SomeService:

```
constructor(
   private router: Router,
   private someOtherService: SomeOtherService
) { }

getSomeData() {
   return this.someOtherService.getSomeOtherData().map(data => {
      if (data === 'someValue') {
         console.log("The data was 'someValue'");
         this.router.navigate(['route1']);
      }
      else if (data == 'someOtherValue') {
         console.log("The data was 'someOtherValue'");
         this.router.navigate(['route2']);
      }
   });
}
```

SomeOtherService:

```
constructor(
   private http: Http
) { }

getSomeOtherData() {
   return this.http.get(this.getDataUrl) {
      .map((res: Response) => {
         console.log("Sending over the data back to SomeService");
         let body = res.json();
         return body.data;
      })
      .catch((err: Response) => {
         console.log(err);
         return Observable.throw(err);
      });
   }
}
```

The expected behavior is that after receiving the data from SomeOtherService, the Router will navigate to either `route1` or `route2` depending on the data (which I thought I read somewhere would stop the Observable stream? Maybe I misread). If the data doesn't match, then the Observable stream continues to SomeComponent which then navigates to `home`.

The actual behavior is that the Router will initially route to `route1` or `route2` but since the stream continues, the Router then finally routes to `home`.

So my question is, if you subscribe to an rxjs Observable, is there a way to cancel/unsubscribe to the Observable mid-stream? I thought that navigating to another route would cancel the observable but this didn't seem to work for me.

I tried unsubscribing within the `map` method with interesting(ly bad) results. I also tried looking at other Observable methods but being new to rxjs I wasn't sure which method would be most appropriate (I'm really only familiar with `map`, `catch`, `mapTo`, and `(sort of) switchMap` at this point).

Comment: If your only observable is one generated by the `this.http.get`, then that observable terminates automatically when the response is returned. No need to cancel it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The expected behavior is that after receiving the data from SomeOtherService, the Router will navigate to either route1 or route2 depending on the data (which I thought I read somewhere would stop the Observable stream? Maybe I misread). If the data doesn't match, then the Observable stream continues to SomeComponent which then navigates to home.

Not quite :-)

Navigating to another view completes all `Observables` provided by the old `ActivatedRoute`. The `Observables` you created are not obtained from an `ActivatedRoute` (nor tied to an `ActivatedRoute` by other means), and will therefore exist independent of which route is active.

Also, `router.navigate(...)` is an asynchronous operation, meaning it only schedules a navigation, but does not wait for navigation to complete. That is, even if your `Observables` were tied to the `ActivatedRoute`, they would still be alive, and their Observers notified.

You can fix this using:

```
constructor(
   private router: Router,
   private someOtherService: SomeOtherService
) { }

getSomeData() {
   return this.someOtherService.getSomeOtherData().map(data => {
      if (data === 'someValue') {
         console.log("The data was 'someValue'");
         return ['route1'];
      }
      else if (data == 'someOtherValue') {
         console.log("The data was 'someOtherValue'");
         return ['route2'];
      } else {
         return null;
      }
   });
}
```

and use it like:

```
this.someService.getSomeData().subscribe({
  next: (route) => {
     this.router.navigate(route || ['home']);
  },
  error: (err) => {
     console.log("Some error occurred.", err);
  }
});
```

BTW, to better understand what an `Observable` is, you may want to read the [ReactiveX documentation](http://reactivex.io/documentation/observable.html).

Comment: This solves what I'm trying to achieve. But just so that I'm clear, is a good summary that Observables can only emit values and only the Observer is able subscribe to/unsubscribe from Observables? Therefore an Observable can't simply stop emitting values downstream, ending the lifecycle of the Observer(s)/Observable?

Comment: An Observable may send `next`, `completed`, or `error` events. `completed` and `error` are terminal events. So yes, an `Observable` may decline to send further values to its `Observers`. Your code did not do so, because you used the map operator, which emits the return value of the mapping function (`undefined` in your case). You could use a `flatMap` operator instead, or do the notification by hand as in Jagers answer, but I find my solution easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to unsubscribe from an observable

The most straightforward way is to keep an handle for the subscription and unsubscribe for example in the OnDestroy method.

```
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Rx'

...

private sub: Subscription;

constructor(
   private someService: SomeService,
   private router: Router
) { }

ngOnInit() {
   this.sub = this.someService.getSomeData().subscribe(..)
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.sub) this.sub.unsubscribe();
}
```

Also doing the navigate in the map() method is a bit strange. The map() operator is used to transform an observable stream to another stream, it is not an endpoint. So usually you'd return something like `someObs.map(s => s.name).subscribe()`. If you only want to do something you could use the `do()` operator instead.

But in your case if data === 'someValue' you would first navigate to route1 in the map operator. Then the subscription callback (next()) is fired and the router navigates to 'home'.

To get the functionality you described you could do it as such:

SomeComponent:

```
constructor(
   private someService: SomeService,
   private router: Router
) { }

ngOnInit() {
   this.someService.getSomeData().subscribe({
      next: () => {
         console.log("getSomeData() did not route to a new link! Routing to a 3rd link");
         this.router.navigate(['home']);
      },
      complete: () => {},
      error: (err) => {
         console.log("Some error occurred.", err);
      }
    });
```

SomeService:

```
constructor(
   private router: Router,
   private someOtherService: SomeOtherService
) { }

getSomeData() {
   return Observable.create(observer => {
    this.someOtherService.getSomeOtherData().first().subscribe(data => {
      if (data === 'someValue') {
         console.log("The data was 'someValue'");
         this.router.navigate(['route1']);
      }
      else if (data == 'someOtherValue') {
         console.log("The data was 'someOtherValue'");
         this.router.navigate(['route2']);    
      } else {
         // none of the options above. call next() on the observer so 
         // it will route to 'home'
         observer.next();
      }
      observer.complete();

   });
});


}
```

Comment: This idea of using the complete() method of the observer as an empty stop to the observable stream works. I determined, however, that meriton's answer is better as all routing is finally handled by the observer itself and the observables just emit the necessary data values back to the observer.